# How to assign variable to Data Validation Formula1:= in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to assign a variable `Rng` to `Formula1:=.`

```
Function DisplayName()

Dim iLastRow As Integer ' This variable will get Last Cell which is not empty in a Column
Dim Rng As Variant ' This variable is created for Dynamic Range selection in a sheet2 named as "BM"

Dim sheetRef As Worksheet
Set sheetRef = Sheets("BM")

iLastRow = sheetRef.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Rng = sheetRef.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow)

    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
          Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Rng
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = "Select From List"
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Function
```

The following error message points to `.Add Type:=`

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

If I remove the variable and place `"=Sheet2!A2:A99"` it works.

Comment: I think you are looking for the [`Range.Formula`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx) property rather than an actual `Range` object

Comment: When pasting code, please indent it by 4 spaces to show the code as a block. Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way is to represent `Formula1` as a string separated by comma. So use `Join`, `Split` to convert your variable to this format. Didn't test it for `Range`, but for `d() as string` it'd be `valueFormula = Join(d, ",")`, `Formula1:=valueFormula`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and did not try it via `... With ActiveCell.Validation: .Delete: .Add ...` but via **`.Modify ...`** (`Formula1` is read-only), which worked:

```
ActiveCell.Validation.Modify Formula1:= ...
```

(So with your code the value could be `"=Sheet2!A2:A99"`, `sheetRef.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow).Text` or `Rng.Text` (no need for `Set` when using `.Text`) I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem this essentially worked for me. The formula1 parameter accepts a string so...

```
Function DisplayName()

    Dim iLastRow As Integer ' This variable will get Last Cell which is not empty in a Column
    Dim formulaString As String

    iLastRow = Sheets("BM").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    formulaString = "='BM'!A2:A" & iLastRow

    With ActiveCell.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=formulaString
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = "Select From List"
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Set` keyword when changing the value of a variable of type `Range`. Change your line to:

```
Set Rng = sheetRef.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow)
```

[See here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html) for more info.

Comment: Hi nicholas, I tried this. it doesn't work even if i set it

Comment: Here it is, 
Run-time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: As per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840078.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the value for `Formula1` needs to be of type `Variant` where as currently you're trying to give it a range.